# what I do share data in sqlserver enterprise for server?

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server

I want to create a web editing services using ArcGIS Server, but the following error occurs when I add an editor task and click on configure. "No Editable layers found".

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: IS the DB connection you have made in ArcGIS for desktop as a user that has read/write privileges?

Comment: Are you adding as a query layer? Is it SQL Server geometry? Is it a geodatabase?  Include more information in your Q and we can answer.